# callback function do background jobs after the completing the action in java spring

Tags: java, spring

I am new to Java Spring Framework, I am Rails developer I have requirement in java spring like I need to do background jobs but after the response send to the end User. It should not wait for the jobs to complete. But the  jobs should run every time  action completes.

Is a webservice app. We have Service, Bo and DAO layers and we are logging  any exceptions occurred while processing the user data in database before response send to user, but now we want to move(Exception handling) after response send to user to increase the performance.

I remember in rails we have callbacks/filters after the action executed it calls the methods we want to executed. Same is available in java Spring?

Thanks,
Senthil

Answer (score 0):

I assume the use case is something like a user requests a long-running task, and you want to return a response immediately and then launch the task in the background.

Spring can help with this. See

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html

In particular see the `@Async` annotation.

With respect to the client getting a response back following the async processing (exception or otherwise), you can do it, but it's extra work.

Normally the immediate response would include some kind of ID that the client could come back with after some period of time. (For example, when you run a search against the Splunk API, it gives you a job ID, and you come back later with that job ID to check on the result). If this works, do that. The client has to poll but the implementation is the simplest.

If not, then you have to have some way for the client to listen for the response. This could be a "reply-to" web service endpoint on the client (perhaps passed in with the original request as a custom `X-Reply-To` HTTP header), or it could be a message queue, etc.

Comment: @Wille Wheeler, Thanks for your time. I didn't gone through complete your link but it seems like jobs scheduler is there any way like  after complete execute controller/action call this jobs like that.

Comment: Is this a web app? If so, then calling the controller isn't going to help if you're trying to communicate the result back to the user, because the user request has already completed. You might elaborate your question with some specifics on what you are trying to do.

Comment: Yes is a webservice app. We have Service, Bo and DAO layers and we are inserting any exceptions occurred in database before response send to user but now we want to move(Exception while processing) after response send to user to increase the performance.

Comment: Edit your question itself (not just adding a comment here) with the specifics please. That will give you more room to explain, and it will give others a chance to answer your question. :-)